# Is there a shot of Darth Vader where his mouth is visible?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

Only reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to make a reverse of my profile photo, where Vader's face is on Anakin's body.

**Is there a shot of Darth Vader where his mouth is visible?**

Comment: https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/open-uri20150608-27674-1t08ej6_c4b09b0e.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C1200%2C675

Comment: http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/13300000/Anakin-Skywalker-SW-ep-III-Birth-and-Death-anakin-skywalker-13343808-852-480.jpg

Comment: I've downvoted because this question shows zero research effort.

Comment: There is also the shot of Vader's force ghost in Return of the Jedi, originally played by Sebastian Shaw. http://www.coolstuffgames.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ghost.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few depending on what age of Darth Vader you want.

[image: Close up of Anakin on Mustafar, Obi-Wan stands behind him staring at him] [image: Closeup of Anakin as he burns from the fire/lava; he stares with all his hatred at Obi-Wan]

[image: Anakin lays on the medical tablewith the suit on for the first time, the face mask of the helmet is being lowered onto his scarred head] [image: Anakin's scarred and pale white head after Luke removes his helmet]

Comment: Thanks! Though I need to look for a front view of Vader like how my profile picture is.

Comment: @Vadakin Your profile image here is just the letter e. It might be worth editing the question to add the image of what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

The best one I could find was (that best describes what you might need):

[image: Darth Vader without his helmet on, his head is pale white and covered in scars]
 <sub>*David Prowse as Vader*</sub>

[[image: Backstage image of Hayden as Vader in the makeup from being burnt in the lava river: his body is shown to be blistered and burnt; he has no hair]  [image: Same as the previous image but a close up of his head/face]]
 <sub>*Hayden Christensen as Vader*</sub>

However, this isn't of much use until you give us a proper reference point of what exactly you need (add the picture of Anakin over which you'd like to put Vader's face).